# Compare two array of objects of same/different size and return a property from first array based on condition

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays like below

```
    arrayOne = [{objectType: 'License', objectName: 'Test Object 1'},
                {objectType: 'Owner', objectName: 'Test Object 2'},
                {objectType: 'Location', objectName: 'Test Object 3'},
                {objectType: 'Job', objectName: 'Test Object 6'}]
            
    arrayTwo = [{objectType: 'License', objectName: 'Test Object 1', dataType: 'String'},
                {objectType: 'Owner', objectName: 'Test Object 2', dataType: 'Value List'},
                {objectType: 'Prop', objectName: 'Test Object 5', dataType: 'Number'}]
```

How can I compare these two arrays and get the values from `arrayOne`, if it doesn't available in `arrayTwo`.

In my example, I need to get the `objectType` values `Location` and `Job` as they are not present in `arrayTwo`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How far have you been ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that checks a `seen` object if the `objectType` value already exists in the `arrayTwo`, and pushes the `arrayOne` object into `arrayTwo` if not:

```js
const arrayOne = [
  {objectType: 'License', objectName: 'Test Object 1'},
  {objectType: 'Owner', objectName: 'Test Object 2'},
  {objectType: 'Location', objectName: 'Test Object 3'},
  {objectType: 'Job', objectName: 'Test Object 6'}];
const arrayTwo = [
  {objectType: 'License', objectName: 'Test Object 1', dataType: 'String'},
  {objectType: 'Owner', objectName: 'Test Object 2', dataType: 'Value List'},
  {objectType: 'Prop', objectName: 'Test Object 5', dataType: 'Number'}];

const seen = arrayTwo.reduce((acc,obj) => {
  acc[obj.objectType] = true;
  return acc;
}, {});
arrayOne.forEach(obj => {
  if(!seen[obj.objectType]) {
    arrayTwo.push(obj);
  }
});
console.log(arrayTwo);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "objectType": "License",
    "objectName": "Test Object 1",
    "dataType": "String"
  },
  {
    "objectType": "Owner",
    "objectName": "Test Object 2",
    "dataType": "Value List"
  },
  {
    "objectType": "Prop",
    "objectName": "Test Object 5",
    "dataType": "Number"
  },
  {
    "objectType": "Location",
    "objectName": "Test Object 3"
  },
  {
    "objectType": "Job",
    "objectName": "Test Object 6"
  }
]
```